AzureDevOps build pipeline takes too long after webpack upgrade(more then one hour)
I joined a project which has a ci/cd pipeline, Recently i did some updates/upgrades on some dependencies spacially webpack version from "webpack": "^4.46.0" to "webpack": "^5.70.0", also i upgrade node js version on pipeline from 14.X to 18.X now when we run pipeline build takes approximately more then one hour and cancled after that. The Application itself is not so huge,  Bellow you can see the my YAML file :
trigger:
- none

pool:
  name: Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  demands: azureps

variables:
  ${{ if or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'develop'),eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'azure-pipelines')) }}:
    storageURL:...
    appGuid: ...
    appRegGuid: ...
    envFullName: development
    envSuffix: -dev
    envShortName: dev 
    adApiId: ...
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'staging') }}:
    storageURL: ...
    appGuid: ...
    appRegGuid: ...
    envFullName: staging 
    envSuffix: -staging
    envShortName: staging 
    adApiId: ...
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}:
    storageURL: ...
    appGuid: ...
    appRegGuid: ...
    envFullName: production 
    envSuffix: 
    envShortName: prod 
    adApiId: ...

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: BuildOfficeAddin
    steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'manifest storage URL replace'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: '((Get-Content manifest.xml.template -Raw) -replace ''%STORAGE_URL%'',''$(storageURL)'') | Set-Content manifest.$(envFullName).xml'
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'manifest app registration replace'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: '((Get-Content manifest.$(envFullName).xml -Raw) -replace ''%APP_REGISTRATION_ID%'',''$(appRegGuid)'') | Set-Content manifest.$(envFullName).xml'
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'manifest app guid replace'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: '((Get-Content manifest.$(envFullName).xml -Raw) -replace ''%APP_GUID%'',''$(appGuid)'') | Set-Content manifest.$(envFullName).xml'
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'manifest app name replace'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: '((Get-Content manifest.$(envFullName).xml -Raw) -replace ''%APP_NAME%'',''$(envSuffix)'') | Set-Content manifest.$(envFullName).xml'
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'manifest env shortName replace'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: '((Get-Content manifest.$(envFullName).xml -Raw) -replace ''%ENV_SHORTNAME%'',''$(envShortName)'') | Set-Content manifest.$(envFullName).xml'
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: '.env storage URL replace'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: '((Get-Content .env.template -Raw) -replace ''%STORAGE_URL%'',''$(storageURL)'') | Set-Content .env.$(envFullName)'
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: '.env for $(envFullName)'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: '(((((Get-Content .env.$(envFullName) -Raw) -replace ''%REACT_APP_ENV%'',''$(envFullName)'') -replace ''%API_URL%'',''https://api$(envSuffix).lexor.be'') -replace ''%B2CDOMAIN%'',''flexsoftlexor$(envShortName)'') -replace ''%ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_API_ID%'',''$(adApiId)'') | Set-Content .env.$(envFullName)'
      - task: NodeTool@0
        displayName: 'Use Node 18.x'
        inputs:
          versionSpec: 18.x
      - task: Npm@1
        displayName: 'npm install'
        inputs:
          verbose: false
      - task: Npm@1
        displayName: 'npm run validate manifest.$(envFullName).xml'
        inputs:
          verbose: false
      - task: Npm@1
        displayName: 'npm run build'
        inputs:
          command: custom
          verbose: false
          customCommand: 'run build:$(envFullName)'
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist'
          TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        displayName: 'Copy Assets to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/assets'
          TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/assets'
      - task: ArchiveFiles@2
        displayName: 'Archive $(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'

this is my package.json :
{
  "name": "office-addin",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "config": {
    "app_to_debug": "word",
    "app_type_to_debug": "desktop",
    "dev_server_port": 3000
  },
  "scripts": {
    "init": "npm run init:env && npm run lingui:compile",
    "init:env": "cp .env.template .env.development",
    "build:development": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --env TARGET_ENV=development  --env HTTPS=true",
    "build:staging": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --env TARGET_ENV=staging --env HTTPS=true",
    "build:production": "webpack -p --config webpack.config.js --env TARGET_ENV=production  --env HTTPS=true",
    "convert-to-single-host": "node convertToSingleHost.js",
    "configure-sso": "office-addin-sso configure manifest.xml",
    "build-dev": "webpack --mode development --https false && echo . && echo . && echo . && echo Please use 'build:dev' instead of 'build-dev'.",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --env TARGET_ENV=development",
    "lint": "office-addin-lint check",
    "lint:fix": "office-addin-lint fix",
    "prettier": "office-addin-lint prettier",
    "start": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml",
    "start:desktop": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml desktop",
    "start:web": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml web",
    "start:server": "office-addin-sso start manifest.xml",
    "stop": "office-addin-debugging stop manifest.xml",
    "validate": "office-addin-manifest validate",
    "watch": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "modules:install": "npm i --legacy-peer-deps",
    "modules:reset": "rm -rf ./node_modules && npm i",
    "modules:update": "./node_modules/.bin/npm-check --update",
    "lingui:extract": "lingui extract --clean",
    "lingui:compile": "lingui compile",
    "lingui:all": "npm run lingui:extract && npm run lingui:compile"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.6.6",
    "@azure/msal-node": "^2.6.5",
    "@fluentui/react": "^8.70.0",
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "@lingui/core": "^3.10.4",
    "@lingui/macro": "^3.10.2",
    "@lingui/react": "^3.10.2",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js": "^3.1.4",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.6.4",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "apollo-link-error": "^1.1.13",
    "common-tags": "^1.8.0",
    "core-js": "^3.22.7",
    "date-fns": "^2.22.1",
    "dot-prop-immutable": "^2.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "framer-motion": "^6.2.8",
    "graphql": "^16.0.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "localforage": "^1.9.0",
    "localforage-memoryStorageDriver": "^0.9.2",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "make-plural": "^6.2.2",
    "mocha": "^8.2.1",
    "msal": "^1.3.2",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "query-string": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-popper": "^2.2.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-select": "^4.3.1",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^2.0.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7",
    "round-to": "^5.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "use-deep-compare-effect": "^1.6.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.6.3",
    "@dashdot/eslint-config-react": "^0.2.0",
    "@lingui/cli": "^3.10.2",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.20",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.1.4",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^12.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.3.6",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-office-addins": "^0.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^4.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "find-process": "^1.4.4",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "less": "^3.9.0",
    "less-loader": "^12.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.8.1",
    "npm-check": "^5.9.2",
    "office-addin-cli": "^1.5.9",
    "office-addin-debugging": "^4.3.14",
    "office-addin-dev-certs": "^1.12.2",
    "office-addin-lint": "^2.2.9",
    "office-addin-manifest": "^1.8.1",
    "office-addin-prettier-config": "^1.2.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "postcss-loader": "^8.1.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.4",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "prettier": "office-addin-prettier-config"
}


Also take a look the picture of the particular step times :
enter image description here
i tried vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest' and vmImage: 'macos-latest' but this not resolf the problem also the there is no problem with the build in my local machine

As suggested in my answer below, you can try to use the CmdLine@2 or Npm@0 task to run the npm commands. @SeifFerhi

I tested with the Npm@1 task and can reproduce the similar issue that the "npm run build" or "npm run test" command gets stuck and final gets cancelled by time-out.
However, the following two ways can work fine when I tried them in the pipeline:

Using the CmdLine@2 task to run the npm commands.
- script: 'npm run build'
  displayName: 'npm run build'


Using the Npm@0 task run the npm commands.
- task: Npm@0
  displayName: 'npm run build'
  inputs:
    command: run
    arguments: build



Looks like, there is problem on the Npm@1 task. As the workaround, you can try to use the CmdLine@2 or Npm@0 task to run the npm commands.

